# Spark window function "rowsBetween" should consider only complete set of rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using "rowsBetween" window function to calculate moving median as below

```
val mm = new MovingMedian
var rawdataFiltered = rawdata.withColumn("movingmedian", mm(col("value")).over( Window.partitionBy("raw_data_field_id").orderBy("date_time_epoch").rowsBetween(-50,50)) )
```

I am taking a window of 50 rows ahead and 50 rows behind my current row.
But I need to exclude any rows in the beginning and towards the end which doesn't have 50 rows ahead or behind current row.

ref code:

```
class MovingMedian extends org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType =
    org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField("value", org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType) :: Nil)

  def bufferSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType(
    org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField("window_list", org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType(org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType, false)) :: Nil
  )
  def dataType: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType = org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType
  def deterministic: Boolean = true
  def initialize(buffer: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double]()
  }
  def update(buffer: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer,input: org.apache.spark.sql.Row): Unit = {
    var bufferVal=buffer.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0).toBuffer
    bufferVal+=input.getAs[Double](0)
    buffer(0) = bufferVal
  }
  def merge(buffer1: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: org.apache.spark.sql.Row): Unit = {
    buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double]](0) ++ buffer2.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double]](0)
  }
  def evaluate(buffer: org.apache.spark.sql.Row): Any = {
      var sortedWindow=buffer.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0).sorted.toBuffer
      var windowSize=sortedWindow.size
      if(windowSize%2==0){
          var index=windowSize/2
          (sortedWindow(index) + sortedWindow(index-1))/2
      }else{
          var index=(windowSize+1)/2 - 1
          sortedWindow(index)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by the window size:

```
val df = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toDF("foo")
val win = Window.orderBy("foo").rowsBetween(-1, 1)

df.select($"foo",
          collect_list($"foo") over win as "agg",
          count($"*") over win as "cnt")
  .filter($"cnt" === 3)
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+---+
|foo|      agg|cnt|
+---+---------+---+
|  2|[1, 2, 3]|  3|
|  3|[2, 3, 4]|  3|
|  4|[3, 4, 5]|  3|
+---+---------+---+
```